# Putting MQ message in a queue

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I have a software where i drop MQMessages through C# software. 
First: i receive a message from MQ as XML message string, i do some Data processing and then i prepare XML file and drop it in the response Queue. 
i set the Correlation Id of the Request message as same as the response message as well as the `MessageId` like this:

```
MQMessage _msg = new MQMessage();
_msg.Encoding = 273;
_msg.CharacterSet = 37;
_msg.Format = "MQSTR";
_msg.CorrelationId = message.CorrelationId;
_msg.MessageId = message.MessageId;
```

where message is the message i receive (Request message) and `_msg` is the response message that i put (Response message)

In IBM side when i receive the response message, I check the correlation Id with the correlationId of the request message and it fails.

Here is how i put the message in the queue:

```
 qmgr.AccessQueue(message.ReplyToQueueName.Trim(), MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT 
 + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING, QueueManagerName, DynamicQueueName, "").Put(_msg);
```

What is missing in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the world are you doing?

> i set the Correlation Id of the Request message as same as the
>   response message as well as the MessageId like this:

Bad, very bad design and goes against the MQ messaging pattern.

(1) Do not set the CCSID and Encoding, you should use the default values and let MQ do the work.

(2) The proper messaging pattern is to set the response message's CorrelationId with the request message's MessageId.  That is how you tie things together.

Your code should look like:

```
MQMessage outMsg = new MQMessage();
outMsg.Encoding = MQC.MQENC_NATIVE;
outMsg.CharacterSet = MQC.MQCCSI_DEFAULT;
outMsg.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
outMsg.MessageId = MQC.MQMI_NONE;
outMsg.CorrelationId = inMsg.MessageId;
```

What in the world is this?

```
qmgr.AccessQueue(message.ReplyToQueueName.Trim(), MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT 
 + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING, QueueManagerName, DynamicQueueName, "").Put(_msg);
```

OMG.  Let me count the ways you have messed this up.  You are creating a temporary dynamic queue based on the name in the 'message.ReplyToQueueName' field, then you put the message to the temporary dynamic queue and finally when the program ends (or you actually close the queue), the queue is deleted (along with your message).

This is the proper way to do it:

```
MQQueue outQ = null;
MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
try
{
   outQ = qmgr.AccessQueue( inMsg.ReplyToQueueName.Trim(),
                            MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING );

   outQ.Put(outMsg, pmo);
}
catch (MQException mqe)
{
   System.Console.WriteLine("MQException CC=" + mqe.CompletionCode + " : RC=" + mqe.ReasonCode);
}
finally
{
   try
   {
      if (outQ != null)
         outQ.Close();  // Close the Queue
   }
   catch (MQException mqe)
   {
      System.Console.WriteLine("MQException CC=" + mqe.CompletionCode + " : RC=" + mqe.ReasonCode);
   }
}
```